# "from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder" fails after update of packages in Anaconda

Tags: python, scikit-learn, anaconda

recently I updated packages in anaconda in order to install keras, and tensorflow. Now my program fails on the next line:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder.

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-83540d56f55d>", line 1, in <module>
    from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder

  File "/Users/teologov/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py", line 134, in <module>
    from .base import clone

  File "/Users/teologov/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .utils.fixes import signature

  File "/Users/teologov/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .validation import (as_float_array,

  File "/Users/teologov/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 18, in <module>
    from ..utils.fixes import signature

  File "/Users/teologov/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/fixes.py", line 144, in <module>
    from scipy.sparse.linalg import lsqr as sparse_lsqr  # noqa

  File "/Users/teologov/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/__init__.py", line 114, in <module>
    from .isolve import *

  File "/Users/teologov/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/isolve/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .iterative import *

  File "/Users/teologov/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/isolve/iterative.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import _iterative

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/teologov/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/isolve/_iterative.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libgfortran.3.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/teologov/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/isolve/_iterative.cpython-36m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Could you please help me to fix it.

Comment: What versions of anaconda and sklearn are you using?

Comment: @DemetriP anaconda v1.6.6 & sklearn v0.19.1

Comment: @DemetriP so I checked the versions:
`anaconda                  custom           py36ha4fed55_0  
anaconda-client           1.6.6            py36hd86ed11_0  
anaconda-navigator        1.6.11                   py36_0  
anaconda-project          0.8.2            py36h9ee5d53_0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstallation from scratch fixed the issue, there was some conflict of versions in the installed packages.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i upgrade the scikit learn package.
go to anaconda navigator then environments then search for scikit learn

then upgrade it and also upgrade scipy along with it(same process)